# Blender doesn't update after I change keyframe positions with script

Tags: keyframes, grease-pencil

Hi I'm creating a suite of a few small functions which manipulate the position of grease pencil keyframes.

My script works but Blender doesn't seem to use these new values until I click somewhere into the dopesheet.

```
class GPencilRippleMoveRight(Operator, AddObjectHelper):
"""move keyframes right"""
bl_idname = "outliner.ripplemoveright"
bl_label = "Ripple Move Greasepencil Keyframes"
bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'}


def execute(self, context):

    for layer in bpy.context.object.data.layers:
        keyframes = layer.frames.values()
        keyframeCount = len(keyframes)

        if keyframeCount==0: # no keyframes
            continue

        selectedKeyframes = []

        for kf in keyframes:
            if kf.select == True: 
                selectedKeyframes.append(kf)
        
        if len(selectedKeyframes)==0: # no keyframes selected
            continue

        firstSelected = selectedKeyframes[0]        


        for kf in keyframes:
            if kf.frame_number >= firstSelected.frame_number:
                kf.frame_number += 1


    # trick to update the display of keyframes in the dopesheet    
    bpy.context.scene.frame_current+=1 
    bpy.context.scene.frame_current-=1

    return {'FINISHED'}
```

Just try this code while playing a grease pencil loop, you will see the animation doesn't change until you click somewhere or call a standard operator of Blender like pressing <kbd>G</kbd>.

So I guess I need to force Blender to update and use the new values somehow – any ideas?

EDIT:
Ok I found a fix: by switching the object's mode it would update:

```
origMode=  str(bpy.context.object.mode)
if final_mode == 'EDIT_GPENCIL':
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='SCULPT_GPENCIL')
else:
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT_GPENCIL')    
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode=origMode)
```

BUT .... when I loop through `selected_editable_objects` to use the script on more than one Grease Pencil Object, they dont have the function `set_mode`.

Is there any other way to achieve this ??

EDIT2: ok it seems toggling `.show_in_front` also does the trick as do some other properties probably. Now just to find the one with lowest impact.

But if there's is some kind of global refresh of stale data that would better of course.

Comment: I wrote an [addon](https://github.com/bergamote/greaspencil_nudge_frames) with a similar functionality and I used `bpy.ops.transform.transform(mode='TIME_TRANSLATE', value=(1,0,0,0))` to move the selected frames. Dunno if that would work for you but it updates the screen automatically.

Comment: @wilks . that nudging was my first idea too untill i realized i cannot manipulate the animation with it  while playing the animation (loop). but thanx illl try to use that. does it work for gp and normal keyframes ?